# reactjs compontent control with useState

Tags: reactjs

I am using the react hook useState to control some HTML.  The problem that I have is I can not update the state.
What it should do is that when a user presses the button 
`<button type="button" onClick={(e)=>{add(product,category,quantity,cart)}}>Clickie</button>`.  It will trigger the `add()` and then check to see if product and quantity are empty.

So far it works as it should, however I can not update the states that I am using to control weither a message is shown or not.  I have two useStates `const [checkProduct, setCheckProduct] = useState(true)
    const [checkQuantity, setCheckQuantity] = useState(true)` and inside my function I want to change them to false if the variables are empty.  However, it is the change that does not work.

What it should be doing is if the variables are empty checkProduct & checkQuantity should be false.  Else, they should be true.

```
const Header = (props) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState('');
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('');
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
    const [checkProduct, setCheckProduct] = useState(true)
    const [checkQuantity, setCheckQuantity] = useState(true)
    let cart = false;
    const a = []
        for(let x in props.cat)a.push(x)
    const add = (product,category,quantity,cart) =>{
        console.log(checkProduct+' ' +checkQuantity)
        if(product===''){
            setCheckProduct(false)
        } 
        if(quantity===''){
            setCheckQuantity(false)
        }

        if(checkProduct && checkQuantity===true){
        props.add(product,category,quantity,cart)
        setCheckQuantity(true)
            setCheckProduct(true)


        }   
        console.log(checkProduct+' ' +checkQuantity)
        setProduct('')
        setQuantity('')
    }
    return(
        <div id='header'>
                <input type="text" value={product} onChange={(e)=>setProduct(e.target.value)}/>
                {!checkProduct ?<span>Please enter an item</span>:null}
                <select id='category' defaultValue={'default'} onChange={(e)=>setCategory(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value='default'>Please choose a category</option>
                    {a.map((x,index)=><option value={x} key={index}>{x}</option>)   }
                </select>
                <input id='quantity' type="number" value={quantity} onChange={(e)=>setQuantity(e.target.value)}/>
                {!checkQuantity ? <span>Please enter an quantity</span>:null}
                <br/>
                <button type="button" onClick={(e)=>{add(product,category,quantity,cart)}}>Clickie</button>
        </div>)
}
export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the setState is asynchronous. It will first check your condition here

```
if (checkProduct && checkQuantity === true) {...}
```

before your setCheckProduct(false) and setCheckQuantity(false) will take effect.
You can check the product and quantity itself then you can use the setState like this:

```
 const add = (product, category, quantity, cart) => {

    if (product && quantity) {
      props.add(product, category, quantity, cart);
      setCheckQuantity(true);
      setCheckProduct(true);
    }else{
      setCheckQuantity(false);
      setCheckProduct(false);
    }

    setProduct("");
    setQuantity("");
};
```